# how to sort array in predefined order

Tags: php

I have an array with qtr_month and total_count:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [qtr_month] => Apr-Jun
            [total_count] => 19
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [qtr_month] => Oct-Dec
            [total_count] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [qtr_month] => Jan-Mar
            [total_count] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [qtr_month] => Jul-Sep
            [total_count] => 0
        )

)
```

i need to sort this array by qtr_month first (1.Jan-Mar, 2.Apr-Jun, 3.Jul-Sep, 4.Oct-Dec), and then by total_count.
But how to sort by qtr_month in order which i need?

Comment: Create an associative array that maps the quarter names to numbers. Then you can use that in the comparison function for `usort()`.

Comment: Why are you storing the quarters that way in the first place? You should store quarter numbers in the database, and convert them to strings for display to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

function myCustomSort($aa, $bb)
{
    $order = ['Jan-Mar', 'Apr-Jun','Jul-Sep', "Oct-Dec"];
    $a = array_search($aa['qtr_month'], $order);
    $b = array_search($bb['qtr_month'], $order);

    if ($a == $b) return 0;
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;

}

$neaArray = [

["qtr_month" => 'Apr-Jun', "total_count" => 19], ["qtr_month" => 'Oct-Dec', "total_count" => 1], ["qtr_month" => 'Jan-Mar', "total_count" => 0], ["qtr_month" => 'Jul-Sep', "total_count" => 0]

];

usort($neaArray, "myCustomSort");
print_r($neaArray);

?>
```

Comment: i am grateful to you.....